# Hold a context menu (NSMenu). Don't allow context menu to close when clicked anywhere on window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, contextmenu

I am displaying a context menu on right click in my NSTextField. I am using the following code to pop up context menu in the rightMouseDown event of my NSTextField :

```
- (void) rightMouseDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
  NSMenu* theMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contextual Menu"];

  [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Suggest Link/Movie" action:@selector(openSuggestionMovieLink) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];
  [theMenu setDelegate:self];

  [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:theMenu withEvent:theEvent forView:self];
}
```

I need to stop closing of this context menu when user click anywhere on the window.

I tried doing the same by overriding the mouse down event of the window and not sending the [super mousedown:event] call inside it when context menu is open. This didn't worked.

Also i tried using NSMenu delegate method menuDidClose: and again opening the menu inside it.

```
- (void)menuDidClose:(NSMenu *)menu
{
   NSLog(@"close");
   [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:menu withEvent:nil forView:self];
}
```

But nothing is working for me.

Is there some way to do the same. Please point me in the right direction.
I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you instead tried subclassing NSMenu and overriding

```
- (void)cancelTracking;
- (void)cancelTrackingWithoutAnimation;
```

to modify to suit your custom behavior? What happens?

Comment: Hi, i tried overriding these methods of NSMenu, but they never get called.

Comment: Also according to NSMenu doc, what cancelTracking does is "Dismisses the menu and ends all menu tracking". This is not what i want.